# WMIC Product GET Name - Invalid Class

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, wmic

I am trying to list all of the programs currently on my Windows 8.1 machine. I believe recently installed software is preventing windows from booting up. I have access to the command line and I have been trying to use the wmic product GET Name to see what I can uninstall from the command line. I read that you have to enable the WMI support tools in Management & Monitoring Tools, but I don't have access to that. Does anyone know if I can enable that from the command line so I can figure out why I am ultimately getting a EDIT:0x000021a error on start up.

Answer (score 1):

Try

This is not a full list (wmic). This is only products installed with Windows Installer. There is no feature for everything.

However as I said in my previous post nearly everything is listed in the registry.

So to see it in a command prompt

```
reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /s
```

Also your error code seems invalid. There is no 27a windows error or 0xc000027a NT Status code. It seems wrong for a COM containing NTSTatus 0xd000027a or COM with Windows error 0x8007027a.

**Clean Booting**

Each of the three steps turns of programs, services, and drivers in increasing amounts. Thus narrowing down the possible culprits.

**Clean Boot**

Click Start - All Programs - Accessories - Run and type

msconfig

Then go to the Startup tab. Untick everything. Then go to the Services tab. Tick Hide All Microsoft Services and untick everything that's left.

Reboot. If this solves your problem reenable ½ of the services/startup items until you find which one.

**Advanced Clean Boot**

If the above doesn't help.

Download Autoruns from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx

Start the program by right clicking and choosing Run As Administrator and click Options menu - Filter Options and tick Hide Microsoft entries and clear Include Empty Locations. Untick everything left.

Reboot. If this solves your problem reenable ½ of the items until you find which one.

**Safe Mode**

If the above doesn't help.

Use Safe Mode with Networking if you need internet access.

Click Start - All Programs - Accessories - Run and type

```
msconfig
```

Then go to the Boot tab and click Safe Boot (also tick Network if needed). Reboot. Come back here and untick Safe Boot to return to normal mode.

or

If your computer has a single operating system installed, repeatedly press the F8 key as your computer restarts. You need to press F8 before the Windows logo appears. If the Windows logo appears, you will need to try again. [From Start - Help and Support]

**Startup Repair**

If your computer has a single operating system installed, repeatedly press the F8 key as your computer restarts. You need to press F8 before the Windows logo appears. If the Windows logo appears, you will need to try again. [From Start - Help and Support].

On the Advanced Boot Options screen, use the arrow keys to highlight Repair your computer, and then press ENTER.

Select Startup Repair.

Startup repair makes a log file. See C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\Srt\SrtTrail.txt.

To access if Windows won't start, on the Advanced Boot Options screen, use the arrow keys to highlight Repair your computer, and then press ENTER.

Select Command Prompt.

Type

```
type C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\Srt\SrtTrail.txt |more
```

---

Also type `explorer` in your command prompt and see what happens.

My Explorer fixes listsways of using windows without the graphical shell.

To See if a Fix is Available

In Control Panel (and select Classic view in the left hand pane) choose Problem Reports and Solutions (type problem in Start's search box), go to Problem History, right click your error and choose Check For Solution.

You may also right click and choose Details for more info. Post those details here. The Fault Module Name is the important information.

If the problem affects Control Panel press Winkey + R and type wercon (or type it in a command prompt).

---

Close Explorer and Start a Command Prompt

Close any Explorer windows

Start - All Programs - Accessories - Right click Command Prompt and choose Run As Administrator.

Click Start. Ctrl + Shift + Right click a blank spot (just above the power buttons is one place) then Exit Explorer.

Press Ctrl + Alt + Delete then Task Manager.

Check all explorer processes are closed. On the Process tab select explorer and right click and choose End Process, repeat if more than one explorer in the list.

Then to restart explorer after trying each of the following

Press Ctrl + Alt + Delete and choose Task Manager

In Task Manager click the File menu then New Task (Run) and type explorer

---

**If You Can't Start Explorer at All**

Press Ctrl + Alt + Delete and choose Task Manager

On the Process tab click Show Processes From All Users to elevate to Administrator 
In Task Manager click the File menu then New Task (Run) and type cmd 
Other things you can try typing

```
Explorer
Explorer c:\
Explorer /e,c:\
wercon
control
iexplore
rstrui
```

If you can't start a folder window use the Browse button in the New Task dialog. Remember you need to right click and choose Open rather than double clicking.

---

Comment: I cannot boot into the OS so doing anything that relates to internal windows process (task manager, viewing log files,downloading, running exe, etc) is out of the question. I can currently only enter into the windows repair mode in which I have access to the CMD. I have tried safe mode to no avail as well. The error code was actually 0x000021a. I appreciate your response.

Comment: I'm in a very similar situation, only have access to restore command prompt, typing the `reg query` command is returning nothing. From that restore mode what else could I do ?

Comment: In all this time I still never found a solution. Windows is a complicated system. Were you able to find any other solutions @MauricioGraciaGutierrez?

Comment: I never came back to this again, it stop being relevant sorry